# Loop won't stop even on recall function angular

Tags: angular, loops, http, restart

I generate domain list based on the input inserted to live show the list:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="domain" (input)="generateList()" type="text" name="search" class="form-control" id="inp3" placeholder="Enter your domain">
```

here is the **generateList()** method:

```
domainList: domainEntity[] = [];
tld = ['.com', '.net', '.org','.info','.online', '.tech', '.design', '.group']
generateList() {
      this.domainList = [];
      this.domain = this.domain[0].toUpperCase() + this.domain.slice(1);
      this.tld.forEach(t => {
        let domain = new domainEntity(this.domain.trim().split(' ').join('').concat(t), 'pending');
        this.domainList.push(domain);
      });

      for (let i = 0; i < this.domainList.length; i++) {
        this.domainService.getDomainStatus(this.domainList[i])
        .subscribe(domainAvailability => {
          this.domainList[i].domainStatus = domainAvailability.toString().split(';')[1].split('=')[1];
        },
        error => {
          const domainAvailability = error.error.text;
          this.domainList[i].domainStatus = domainAvailability.toString().split(';')[1].split('=')[1];
          console.log(this.domainList[i].domainName,'****',this.domainList[i].domainStatus);
        });
      }
  }
```

And the problem is when I insert another char in the input,I saw in the log the previous loop still calling getDomainStatus() with the previous input value and I get the new result when it finish.

**Exemple:** I insert "a" the list contains : *['a.com', 'a.net','a.org',...]* and it enters the loop to check the status. And when I type another 'a' the list becomes *['aa.com', 'aa.net','aa.org',...]* and I don't get any domain status untill the first loop finishes from calling getDomainStatus() of the first list.

**Why the loop didn't restart?**

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal reproduction, as a stackblitz. Your explanation isn't very clear to me, and we have no idea of what the code that you didn't post does.

Comment: Which part of the code you want to know?

Comment: I want to have a **complete**, minimal reproduction of the issue. Complete means complete. I.e. without any missing part. Minimal means without all the code that is irrelevant to the issue. So you don't need to post your whole app. Only a minimal but complete app that reproduces the issue, and does only that.

Comment: I added an exemple and updated the code! tell me if there is something not clear please

Comment: Presumably (since you refuse to post the relevant code), this.domainService.getDomainStatus() sends an HTTP request to your server. Since you're sending a request for each element of your array, you send a lot of them. And browsers don't send more than N concurrent requests to the same domain to avoid spamming problems. So all the requests are queued, and the requests for the second list need to wait until the responses from the first list have been received. You should learn about RxJS operators such as debounceTime and switchMap.